# How can I run a bash script from within nodejs and allow the script full permissions?

Tags: node.js, bash, child-process

I am having some issues running a bash script using the `exec` function from within a nodejs file.

The bash script is meant to find all occurrences of "process.env" within the ./src folder.  The bash script is as follows:

```
FOLDERS_TO_SEARCH=./src
test_list=$(grep -r -l "process.env" $FOLDERS_TO_SEARCH)
echo "test_list: $test_list"
envvar_files_list=($(grep -r -l "process.env" $(echo $FOLDERS_TO_SEARCH) | tr '\n' ' '))
echo "envvar_files_list: $envvar_files_list"
envvar_files_arr=(`echo $envvar_files_list`)

for filePath in "${envvar_files_arr[@]}" 
do
    found_destructured=($(cat $filePath | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/  */ /g' | grep -Ezo '\{[^}]*\} = process.env' | sed 's/.*{\([^}]*\)}.*/\1/g' | tr -d ' ' | tr ',' '\n' | tr -d "=''" | awk -F':' '{print $1}'))
done
```

This script runs perfectly in my bash file. When I echo `envvar_files_list`, it will return the full list of files that contain "process.env"

However, if I run this script using the `exec` function in node like so:

```
import { exec } from 'child_process';

exec(
  'bash ./scripts/check_envvars.bash "./db ./src" healthcheck',
  (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    if (error) {
      console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
      return;
    }
  }
);
```

When running this js file, the bash file will only log a singular file when the `echo envvar_files_list: $envvar_files_list"` is run. I get an stdout of:

```
stderr: ./scripts/check_envvars.bash: line 48: ./src/routers/healthcheck/validation.ts: Permission denied
```

However, when the "test_list: $test_list" is logged, it will return the full list. So there is something going on when running `$(grep -r -l "process ......`

```
test_list=$(grep -r -l "process.env" $FOLDERS_TO_SEARCH)
echo "test_list: $test_list"
envvar_files_list=($(grep -r -l "process.env" $(echo $FOLDERS_TO_SEARCH) | tr '\n' ' '))
```

After seeing this permission issue I tried chmod -R `777` & `u+x`:

```
exec(
  'chmod -R u+x ./src && bash ./scripts/check_envvars.bash "./db ./src" healthcheck',
```

I believe this is most likely a permission issue but I just fix it.

Comment: The error looks like the script is attempting to execute one of the ts files it found (which doesn't appear to be the intention).  Is there more to the bash script?

Comment: also [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) will help with most of the shell gotchas, of which there's a few

Comment: thanks I will check it out. Why I am so confused is that this script runs perfectly fine in my own shell (GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release) BUT I call the script from within a node env, it fails. When doing the `envvar_files_list=($(grep...` in my own shell, it returns 30 files. When I run this within node, it only returns a single file. So it's almost like the grep command runs once, finishes, and moves to the next line.